# jQuery ui autocomplete and jScrollPane

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jscrollpane

I'm trying to use jQuery ui autocomplete component with jScrollPane to customize the overflow scrollbar

HTML:

```
<label>Tags</label>
<input type="text" class="input_autocomplete">
```

CSS:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete{
width: 200px;
max-height: 120px;
overflow: auto;
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;

}
ul.ui-autocomplete li{
line-height:29px;
height: 29px;
min-width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
background:#dcdcdc;
}
ul.ui-autocomplete li:nth-child(2n+1){
background:#ebebeb;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", 
    "AppleScript", 
    "Asp", 
    "BASIC", 
    "C", 
    "C++", 
    "Clojure", 
    "COBOL", 
    "ColdFusion", 
    "Erlang", 
    "Fortran", 
    "Groovy", 
    "Haskell", 
    "Java", 
    "JavaScript", 
    "Lisp", 
    "Perl", 
    "PHP", 
    "Python", 
    "Ruby", 
    "Scala", 
    "Scheme",
    "cia cia",
    "bu bu",
    "ih ih ih"];

    var api;
    var autocomplete_init = false;

    $( ".input_autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        open: function(){
                            if(!autocomplete_init){
                               $('ul.ui-autocomplete').addClass('scroll-pane');
               api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane().data('jsp');
                               autocomplete_init = true;
                            } else {
               api.reinitialise();
                            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

the first search is ok, but if I close the autocomplete list and try to reopen with the same research, jScollPane not reinitialize.
Where I wrong?

thanks for your help

Comment: ok, i have updated with html/css code
thanks :)

Comment: Here you'll find what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327892/autocomplete-jquery-ui-plugin-with-custom-scrollbars

Comment: yes I have tryed but it is based on old version of jScrollPane, jQuery ui and jQuery, and trying with the versions (jQuery ui and jQuery) used in my project, I have others problem :(

Comment: Works fine for me on http://jsfiddle.net/md3EC/

Comment: I tried all suggestions but it didn't work, even Anders Lindén fiddle doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code.

```
$( ".input_autocomplete" ).keydown(function(){
    $( this ).autocomplete( "search", $(this).val() );
});
```