# JQuery autocomplete custom scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

i am not able to define a custom scroll bar to the jquery autocomplete widget , no information is there on the jquery site or any other place either

Please suggest if any one has an idea

Regards
Smriti Garg

Comment: This has been answered here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327892/autocomplete-jquery-ui-plugin-with-custom-scrollbars

Comment: HI I had seen the link before but the demo link given there is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

Please follow all comments given there, you will find another link given by vitch. [jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com) Visit this page and you will find what you need.