# Custom scrollbar for jQuery-UI Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to add a custom scrollbar to jQuery-ui Autocomplete widget. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327892/autocomplete-jquery-ui-plugin-with-custom-scrollbars), I tried with jScrollpane (although I'd prefer a lighter solution, such as sbscroller 8k or tinyscrollbar 3k.)

It just won't work for me with current versions of the scripts. It appears to work, but:

A) On first attempt, type Z, the list does not filter & the scroll shows all items.
B) If you backspace and type a new letter, the scrollbar disappears.

```
$("#countries").autocomplete({
    source: countryList,
    open: function(event, ui) {
          $('.ui-autocomplete').jScrollPane();
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
          $('.ui-autocomplete').jScrollPaneRemove();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sJL89/2/
I included a scroll test in the Fiddle.

Comment: You could use http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength to limit your results so that a scroll bar isn't unnecessary.

Comment: Possible, but I was writing a jQuery UI theme, so I wouldn't necessarily be in control of that.  Personally I might switch to http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/, because I like the results better.

Comment: Hi Jennifer, did you find a solution or did you switch to jQuery Chosen?

Comment: I switched to Chosen for simple lists, and Select2 for lists querying database. 
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/